# Is there any way to convert HTML content to readable text in iTextSharp?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core, type-conversion, itext

I am using iTextSharp for creating PDF documents in a .Net Core application. Sometimes I receive a HTML content as below:

```
<p>This is a <strong>bold text</strong> and also\n this is a new line.</p>
```

The result after converting to readable Text, should be: 
This is a **bold text** and also

 this is a new line.

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: Which version of *iTextSharp* do you use? An ancient 4.x or earlier? Then read up on the iTextSharp `HTMLWorker` use. An old 5.x? Then look for iTextSharp `XMLWorker` examples. Or a current iText 7.x? Then use its pdfHtml module.